Flutter all widgets are rebuilding on keyboard open or close
The app looks like this:
ProviderScope(
   child: MaterialApp.router(

I have a bottom nav and the next flow:

Bottom nav at index 0 has a widget A
Widget A has a list and tapping on a list item opens widget B
Widget B has a popupMenuItem that opens widget C
Widget C has a TextFormFiled, and when focus on it keyboards appears and the build method is called again for widget A, widget B and widget C
I'm using HookConsumerWidgets.

This issue appeared after upgrading to Flutter 3.24.3, before it didn't. Maybe there is another option or suggestion than downgrading :)
I'm not using MediaQuery, tried resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false and navigation is done like this:
Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder...


Not sure what's causing it or how to avoid it, but I think in general it shouldn't matter if rebuilds happen. If a rebuild is noticeable by the end user than maybe you need to improve some of your widgets because when properly implemented you wouldn't even notice it when a build is triggered

Correct, the rebuilds are not noticeable, but on the latest widget, the one with the TextFormField, has a "state" that I'm watching inside the build method. And this multiple rebuilding resets the state.

can you add the snippet of the widget in which textform is used?

Without seeing the exact code it is hard to say what causes the issue or what the exact issue even is. Do you use a key in the TextFormField? If there is none it could lead to this behavior. Additionally the didUpdateWidget method could help you obtain information from the widget (not the state) before it got rebuild.

Found the issue, for screen scale the app uses sizer package and after updating to latest version, https://pub.dev/packages/sizer has this issue, I've reported it.
